# TypeError: call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_training' (trying to convert code from TF 1.1.0 to 2.2.0)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to call the `ProbUNet` class using `prob_unet` object in below script. `ProbUNet` class is given after this script. Here I am trying to convert `tf` 1.10 code to TF 2 (at the required places I have replaced `tf.` to `tf.compat.v1.`).

Following is the error message stack:

```
File "/home/bdp954/miniconda3/envs/new/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpunet/bin/train.py", line 363, in train1
    prob_unet(x, y, is_training=True, one_hot_labels=cf.one_hot_labels)
  File "/home/bdp954/miniconda3/envs/new/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_v1.py", line 786, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bdp954/miniconda3/envs/new/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 667, in wrapper
    return converted_call(f, args, kwargs, options=options)
  File "/home/bdp954/miniconda3/envs/new/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 396, in converted_call
    return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options)
  File "/home/bdp954/miniconda3/envs/new/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 478, in _call_unconverted
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_training'
```

Here is the code:

```py
def train1(cf):
    """Perform training from scratch."""

    # do not use all gpus
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = cf.cuda_visible_devices

    # initialize data providers
    data_provider = get_train_generators(cf)
    train_provider = data_provider['train']
    val_provider = data_provider['val']

    prob_unet = ProbUNet(latent_dim=cf.latent_dim, num_channels=cf.num_channels,
                         num_1x1_convs=cf.num_1x1_convs,
                         num_classes=cf.num_classes, num_convs_per_block=cf.num_convs_per_block,
                         initializers={'w': training_utils.he_normal(),
                                       'b': tf.keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(stddev=0.001)},
                         regularizers={'w': tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.5 * (1.0))})
    x = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=cf.network_input_shape)
    y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.uint8, shape=cf.label_shape)
    mask = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.uint8, shape=cf.loss_mask_shape)

    global_step = tf.compat.v1.train.get_or_create_global_step()

    if cf.learning_rate_schedule == 'piecewise_constant':
        learning_rate = tf.compat.v1.train.piecewise_constant(x=global_step, **cf.learning_rate_kwargs)
    else:
        learning_rate = tf.compat.v1.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate=cf.initial_learning_rate,
                                                             global_step=global_step,
                                                             **cf.learning_rate_kwargs)
    with tf.device(cf.gpu_device):
        prob_unet(x, y, is_training=True, one_hot_labels=cf.one_hot_labels)
```

And the class `ProbUNet`:

```py
class ProbUNet(Model):
    """Probabilistic U-Net."""

    def __init__(self,
                 latent_dim,
                 num_channels,
                 num_classes,
                 num_1x1_convs=3,
                 nonlinearity=tf.nn.relu,
                 num_convs_per_block=3,
                 initializers={'w': he_normal(), 'b': tf.compat.v1.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.001)},
                 regularizers={'w': tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.5 * (1.0)),
                               'b': tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.5 * (1.0))},
                 data_format='NCHW',
                 down_sampling_op=lambda x, df: \
                         tf.nn.avg_pool2d(input=x, ksize=[1, 1, 2, 2], strides=[1, 1, 2, 2], padding='SAME',
                                          data_format=df),
                 up_sampling_op=lambda x, size: \
                         tf.image.resize(x, size, method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR),
                 name='prob_unet'):
        super(ProbUNet, self).__init__(name=name)
        self._data_format = data_format
        self._num_classes = num_classes
        # with self._enter_variable_scope():
        # with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope(name):
        self._unet = UNet(num_channels=num_channels, num_classes=num_classes, nonlinearity=nonlinearity,
                          num_convs_per_block=num_convs_per_block, initializers=initializers,
                          regularizers=regularizers, data_format=data_format,
                          down_sampling_op=down_sampling_op, up_sampling_op=up_sampling_op)

        self._f_comb = Conv1x1Decoder(num_classes=num_classes, num_1x1_convs=num_1x1_convs,
                                      num_channels=num_channels[0], nonlinearity=nonlinearity,
                                      data_format=data_format, initializers=initializers, regularizers=regularizers)

        self._prior = \
            AxisAlignedConvGaussian(latent_dim=latent_dim, num_channels=num_channels,
                                    nonlinearity=nonlinearity, num_convs_per_block=num_convs_per_block,
                                    initializers=initializers, regularizers=regularizers, name='prior')

        self._posterior = \
            AxisAlignedConvGaussian(latent_dim=latent_dim, num_channels=num_channels,
                                    nonlinearity=nonlinearity, num_convs_per_block=num_convs_per_block,
                                    initializers=initializers, regularizers=regularizers, name='posterior')

    def _build(self, img, seg=None, is_training=True, one_hot_labels=True):
        """
        Evaluate individual components of the net.
        :param img: 4D image array
        :param seg: 4D segmentation array
        :param is_training: if False, refrain from evaluating the posterior
        :param one_hot_labels: bool, if False expects integer labeled segmentation of shape N1HW or NHW1
        :return: None
        """
        if is_training:
            if seg is not None:
                if not one_hot_labels:
                    if self._data_format == 'NCHW':
                        spatial_shape = img.get_shape()[-2:]
                        class_axis = 1
                        one_hot_shape = (-1, self._num_classes) + tuple(spatial_shape)
                    elif self._data_format == 'NHWC':
                        spatial_shape = img.get_shape()[-3:-1]
                        one_hot_shape = (-1,) + tuple(spatial_shape) + (self._num_classes,)
                        class_axis = 3

                    seg = tf.reshape(seg, shape=[-1])
                    seg = tf.one_hot(indices=seg, depth=self._num_classes, axis=class_axis)
                    seg = tf.reshape(seg, shape=one_hot_shape)
                seg -= 0.5
            self._q = self._posterior(img, seg)

        self._p = self._prior(img)
        self._unet_features = self._unet(img)
```

Could you please help me resolve the issue?

Comment: Is this complete `class ProbUNet`? I do not see any `call` method in it which should be used when you perform `prob_unet(x, y, is_training=True, one_hot_labels=cf.one_hot_labels)`. Also method `ProbUNet._build(...)` which looks similar by signature to your call is private and no `_build` calls inside of class.

Comment: Please extend your code section or provide link to repository you are using as initial one (second is more preferable).

Comment: No, I didn't copy complete ProbUNet class earlier. Now, I am sharing my files with github link: https://github.com/sandeepsinghsengar/PMPU. using line 362 of train.py file, I am trying to call ProbUNet class (line 351) in the probabilistic_unet.py file. Please have a look and let me know for further details. Earlier probabilistic_unet.py and def train1(cf) fuction (line 334 in train.py) were in tensorflow 1.1.0. However, now I changed for TF 2.2.0. another part of train.py was already implemented for tf 2.2.0. There may be some version incompatibility problem.
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: To call a class instance in Python you should have `__call__` method and you do not have one in `ProbUNet`. If you are trying to call logic inside of `_build` method try to change your `prob_unet(x, y, is_training=True, one_hot_labels=cf.one_hot_labels)` to `prob_unet._build(x, y, is_training=True, one_hot_labels=cf.one_hot_labels)` but I am not sure magic will occur. Do you have working code for TF1.X?

Comment: I already tried prob_unet._build(x, y, is_training=True, one_hot_labels=cf.one_hot_labels). But again one more error. I will paste that one soon here.

Comment: Using the above prob_unet._build(x, y, is_training=True, one_hot_labels=cf.one_hot_labels), following is error: https://github.com/sandeepsinghsengar/PMPU/blob/main/slurm-1634231.out